# Velocity with tiles 2 and spring-mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, velocity, tiles2

I am looking for a way to use velocity with tiles 2 :

in the end I want to switch from jsp / vm like this :

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition extends="default" name="view1">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/view1.jspx"/>
    </definition>

    <definition extends="default" name="view2">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/view2.vm" type="velocity"/>
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

What I want to do is exaclty explained here :

http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/integration/velocity.html

The first 2 point are easy but it is not clear what to do in the 3rd point :
I have to override the method : registerAttributeRenderers()

But what is the class to extend ?
Then what should I do with this class, I guess it has to be referenced somewhere in spring...

My current spring-mvc configuration :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="tilesViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

thanks for help !

Comment: why don't you define a `velocityviewresolver` instead of passing velocity files through tiles

Comment: because it is an existing project build with jsp, I wanted to slowly switch to velocity for new views and later convert jsp views to vm (which I guess will never occur)

Comment: You can use both viewresolvers side by side